# Windows Form to Send email

Tags: c#, .net, email

I'm trying to build a windows form with 3 TextBoxt like Sender , Object , Body

To use the SmtpClient feature on .net and following, let users to send me an email using my windows form.

I really can't figure it out and forgive me because I'm just new to c# and I am still learning.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;


namespace ArcadiaPatcher
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(Text1);

        smtpClient.Host = "mail.domain2.com";
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;

        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = Text2;
        //Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;
        message.Body = Text3;
        message.To.Add("recipient");

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




}
```

}

Comment: how can i use what the people put into the text box to send the email? Like message.Subject = Text2;  where text2 is the text filled into private void textBox2_TextChanged

Comment: message.Body = textBox1.Text

Comment: Alex +1 !  Tnx a lot..... i'm learning and i'm not a student... i'm a system administrator approaching to c# -.-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working sample using gmail smtp :

```
    public static MailAddress from = new MailAddress("myAddress@gmail.com","Ramy Mohamed");
    string password = "balabala";
    var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from.Address, password)
        };

       using (var message = new MailMessage(from, SendToAddress.Text)
                {
                    Subject = MySubjectText.Text,
                    Body = MyContentText.Text
                })
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);                        
                }
```